# Hide some dots in Line Chart - react-native-chart-kit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, react-native-svg, react-native-chart-kit

I'm working on Line Chart with [react-native-chart-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit). What I'm trying to achieve is, to show dot on a specific data point only and hide dots for all other points. Is it possible? How can I accomplish this?

This is what I need to display:

[image: Line chart with a dot on a single data point]

Comment: Hey, how were you able to set gradient to the line please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. I achieved this using the `hidePointsAtIndex` prop. It accepts an array of indices of data points that you don't want to display.

Example usage:

```js
<LineChart
  data={data}
  width={screenWidth}
  height={256}
  verticalLabelRotation={30}
  chartConfig={chartConfig}
  withHorizontalLines={false}
  withVerticalLines={false}
  bezier
  hidePointsAtIndex={chartData.map((item, idx) => ((idx !== showDotIndex) && idx) )}
  />
```